# Is there any possible to connect .NET with PHP?

Tags: c#, php, .net

Is there any possible to connect .NET app with PHP? I means, PHP will return XML or JSON file to .NET, and .NET will using the LINQ if the data is XML. If there is possible, how can I do that?

any example?

Comment: What you're looking to do is to create an API between two applications.  This is most certainly possible.  One common approach is to expose a web service, for example.  One application (the PHP one in your example) can expose the service, which could expect and return XML or JSON data.  The other application (the .NET one in your example) would consume the service as a client, interacting with that data.  Without more specifics, that's about as precise as we can get.

Comment: Is it the same way with the android? I have done with the android. The android will do a REST to PHP, and the PHP will return the data.

Comment: Yes. Create a RESTful service in PHP which returns responses as XML or JSON and then consume it in C# with an HttpClient (http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Screencast-Consuming-REST-services-with-HttpClient/)

Comment: It's also possible to use PHPLinq

Comment: You're still trying to connect .NET to PHPMyAdmin, aren't you?  Stop!  Learn the difference between PHPMyAdmin and MySQL.  Learn the difference between a tool and a database.  Then come back to your questions and see how silly they are.

Comment: for marceln, Okay. I will see it first. for Mark Baker, PHPLinq? never hear that. Do you have any example? @TimS. pardon, I think the question is different. I'm not trying to connect .NET to PHPMyadmin. I just want .NET to get some data from my php files (not database). The last question was answered by Jason De Oliviera. thanks! maybe you must read my old question first, saw the answer from Jason, and come back to your answer and see how silly they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a PHP application which returns JSON/ XML. Then in your dot net application you can access that( the same way webservices/REST services being accessed). You may use the `HttpWebRequest` class to access the service like this.

```
string restURL="www.yoursite.com/yourphpwebservice.php";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(restURL);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Accept = "text/xml";
request.ContentType = "text/xml";

response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();              
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    using (WebResponse response2 = request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response2.GetResponseStream())
    {                       
        XElement myXel = XElement.Load(stream);
        if (myXel != null)
        {
          //now you can access the XML elements with LINQtoXML
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. maybe i will try it first. How if I change the request.method to Get?

Comment: @AlfredAngkasa: `request.Method = "GET";` here you are telling it is a GET request.

Comment: I'm sorry. to POST. what will gonna happen? sorry about that. it is already 3.30 AM here. and i feel so sleepy.

Answer (score 0):

If you're returning an XML file via PHP, you can use the .NET `XDocument` class:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");

var query = from xml in xdoc.Descendants("node")
       select new { 
           Attribute1 = lv1.Attribute("Attribute1").Value,
           Attribute2 = lvl1.Attribute("Attribute2").Value
       };
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299195

Comment: But i don't store the xml file into data.xml, Darren. :D if I do like u say, thats mean i already have the xml file first right?